# How Vidarbha from scriptures is same as current Vidarbha?

Tags: geography

The following passage from Wikipedia says that

> The Vidarbha kingdom in the Sanskrit epic Mahabharata is among the
>   many kingdoms ruled by Yadu kings (Bhoja Yadavas). **It is the
>   southernmost kingdom within the epic's geographical horizon, south of
>   the Vindhyarange, in the region still known as Vidarbha in what is now
>   Central India.**

How can it be proved? Are there any mentions to the actual geographical location of Vidarbha in scriptures?